# facebook uploaded photo coming in album, not in wall, that too without comment

Tags: android, facebook

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();       
    params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
    params.putString("message", "Test Photo");
    params.putByteArray("picture", data);
    mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "me/feed",
            new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

i tried this also

```
   mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST",
            new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

i am using this code to upload photo to facebook. but the photo comes in album 'app_name photos'. the comment is also missing. is there any way to upload photo to wall with comment ?

UPDATE :
comments are coming when i added.

```
          params.putString("caption", "Test Photo 2");
```

EDIT:

```
    params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, token);
    params.putString("message", "graph api");   
    mAsyncRunner.request("me/feed", params,"POST", new SampleUploadListener(),null);
```

this is posting the message to wall. but if add a picture, it is not coming on the wall.

```
    params.putByteArray("picture", data);
```

Comment: is it possible with graph api?

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure about the `me/feed` path, but this worked for album:

```
params.putByteArray("source", data);
```

Instead of `picture` and **without** specifying the `method`

Answer (score 0):

The photos that you are uploading through your facebook application whose secret Id you will give in your android application. If fb application on site is not approved by facebook then at this juncture you have to approved the images that gets uploaded to your photos fb account section.

Comment: if you have "publish_stream" permission, all photos will be approved automatically and in my cases photos are coming. but they are coming in album, not in my wall.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for upload photo on facebook wall post.

```
String IMAGE_PATH_FROM_SERVER = "http://................";

Bundle b = new Bundle();

String attachment = "{\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"" + IMAGE_PATH_FROM_SERVER + "\",\"href\":\""+IMAGE_PATH_FROM_SERVER+"\"}]}";

b.putString("attachment", attachment);
sFacebook.dialog(context, "stream.publish", b, new SampleDialogListener());
```

Comment: i want to upload an image from mobile, it is not present in any web server.

Comment: ok,, now u have a local image path , then u have to upload that local image on the server by programmatically.